# Safari adding a ? to page links

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I'm not sure why but on A tag links Safari is adding a "?" to the end of the href (see below). I've searched but can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere. It's a relatively new problem as there haven't been complaints until recently where the links don't work. My current work around is using jQuery to strip off all the "?" if the browser is Safari.

I don't have any javscript or anything that is manipulating the A tags and it's just simple html files, no PHP/.net/c# or anything like that. Server is IIS based and the IT person ruled out any server side problems. Ruling out a Mac OS problem, all other browsers on the Mac side don't do this nor do any of the PC browsers. It's only Safari :(

Does anyone know why Safari is doing this?

All other browsers

```
<a href="javascript:adjQty('VAR');addItems();" class="style1">link</a>
```

Safari

```
<a href="javascript:adjQty('VAR');addItems();?" class="style1">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the question mark? Safari is a fairly old system of HTML running on, which can cause catastrophic glitches etc.

Comment: there is no question mark in the html code at all, Safari seems to be adding it on it's own :(...why i'm using jQuery to remove it.